# how to get the user id logged in and register along with the post he's doing?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am developing a web application and am doing the relationship between tables. I want to do the following: The user will register a printer related to it, the program will get the data that he put in the form and save in the database along with his id to refer to in the other table when I call him.

I tried to do the following:

```
public function savePrinter(Request $request){
        $user = $request->user()->id;

        Printers::create($request->all(), $request->user()->id);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Printers.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Printers extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name_printer',
        'link_printer',
        'printer_id'
    ];

    protected $table = 'printers';
}
```

I want the program to save in the printers table the id of the logged in user to do the reference
Obs

> (the program is saving the correct printer name,I just can not save
>   the logged user's id in `printer_id`)

Comment: In your printers table, do you have `user_id` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In  `Users` Model add this relationship

```
public function Printer() {
     return  $this->hasMany(Printers::class,'printer_id','id');
}
```

> now in your controller add this line

```
 $user = $request->user()->Printer()->create($request->all());
```